# When I navigate to a view, how do I link a viewmodel to it?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I have a basic MVVM light Windows Phone 8 app created. I have MainView, being shown as the startup page. This is automatically getting the datacontext of a new instance of MainViewModel.

I want to navigate to another view, and have a new viewmodel (or an existing one provided on navigation) set as the datacontext for that view.

How do I do this?

I have navigation working through http://mvvmlightnavigation.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MVVMlightNavigationService/NavigationService.cs

Should I be using something else for navigation?

Comment: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/mvvm-in-real-life-windows-phone-applications-part1 may this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the basePage tag in XAML

you can add your view model like this

```
<basepage:BaseApplicationPage 
DataContext="{Binding YourViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

Make sure the you have to registered the ViewModel with the same name that you are giving in the data context. 
I am using MVVMlight, so ViewModel and View are registered in the 'ViewModelLocator'.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is how MVVM light is doing the linking. I thought that it was auto-resolving, like in caliburn.

Comment: My Understanding is that the linking is done through the name in which the ViewModel is registered. Name should be same in the datacontext  as that is ViewModelLocator. So the locator will identify the respective viewmodel.